# Is this expression true and legal?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to write it simple and easy but I'm not sure about precedence

A→B & NOT A→ NOT B ↔ NOT A XOR B = 1

I want to express

((A→B) & (NOT A→ NOT B)) ↔ (((NOT A) XOR B)) = 1

Are the two expressions the same and I can just lose the brackets?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with operator theory.  I would NOT lose the brackets.  The second expression isn't even clear to me, since I don't know whether & or <-> comes first.  Only when you have full parentithesization in logic will you have a well-formed formula.

Comment: So it is of the form $P \leftrightarrow Q = 1$ ??  Perhaps explain how to parse that...

Comment: @NickRosencrantz Given the convention that a&b means (a&b) where & indicates a binary connective, then what you wrote in the comment is unambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((A → B) & ((NOT A) → NOT B)) ↔ ((NOT A) XOR B) = 1`

is by far the best route to go, in terms of being UNambiguous, with "&" corresponding to the connective AND: $\land,\;$, and XOR corresponding to $\oplus$, and $1 = T$ or $True$

Negation can be parsed in a number of ways: in Boolean Logic, one sees $A'$ or $\overline A$ to denote NOT $A$. But in logic, one uses $\lnot A$, and some even use ~$ A$, which when used, apply only to the literal it precedes, unless it precedes a bracketed connected proposition to which it is applied.

So, in propositional logic, the expression would be parsed as follows:

> $$[(A \rightarrow B) \land (\lnot A \rightarrow B)] \longleftrightarrow (\lnot A \oplus B) \quad \equiv \quad T$$

which is to say, $$[(A \rightarrow B) \land (\lnot A \rightarrow B)] \longleftrightarrow (\lnot A \oplus B) \quad \textrm{ is a tautology.}$$

Comment: By the way, Nick, I like your idea of a symbol to introduce examples: if you ever write a text book, and in the Introduction make clear that along with Theorems and Proofs, and Figures, you'll introduce examples with `¤`, then go for it!

Comment: Hey, Nick. We just like to ensure questions have at least one posted answer. You can accept it or not, that's your choice. It seems you knew what you were doing, and just wanted to double check!